# Camel http Servlet IP restriction

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I've googled for a reference of configuring Camel servlet (or route) to restrict processing requests of a list of IPs, but not found any. I'm using spring boot with camel and tried several ways like: to intercept, to define a InterceptStrategy, to extend CamelHttpTransportServlet, override doGet... all of them without success.

I know this is feasible with spring boot servlet, but then I loose flexibility of defining as many routes as needed via XML, just changing URIs. Non-developers are able to work only with XML route definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I forgot the separation of concerns principle...
The solution for my dilemma was to create a filter over Spring Boot web server, something like:

```
public class AllowedIpFilter implements Filter {

@Value("${my.allowed.ip-address}")
private String allowedIpAddress;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
    if(!request.getRemoteAddr().equals(allowedIpAddress)){
        System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr() + " is forbidden");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Not authorized");
        out.flush();
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}

@Override
public void destroy() {}

}
```